# wso2 data services server - CRUD insert using a java generated GUID

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I have an entity that requires a GUID for it's primary key.   Ideally, I would like to use a java class to generate the GUID before adding the entity to the database, so that I can control exactly how the GUID is created.

Is it possible to delegate the key generation to a java class with WSO2 DSS?  How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to generate the GUID within the SQL statement, using ORACLE (for example) functions. I guess you will success if the algorithm is not too complex. This way, your insert statement would look like:

```
Insert into table (c1, c2, ..) values (functions for ID, v2,...)
```

Although the best practice is to use a trigger before insert which call a database sequence to generate a new guid.

You can also try to make a xslt transformation where you implement the algorithm to generate de guid. You would just have to perform the transformation before calling to dss.

Hope it helps!

Comment: would another manual workaround be to create an AXIS service that sits in front of (i.e. proxies) the INSERT data services.  This second service could generates GUIDS and pass the GUID to the INSERT DSS queries?  All clients would access only the second service.

Comment: Yep, the first one would be published in the ESB, where you generate the guid (custum mediator in Java, javascript code, the simpliest one I think) and add it to the message before sending to the dss. If you can have this scenario (2 services), this choice is the best one for me.

Comment: I guess one other option would be to create an axis2 [module](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Writing+an+Axis2+Module)  to intercept the `INSERT` requests and generate a GUID?

Comment: Yep, but I would choose the ESB based design if there is an ESB avaliable in your environment, since I think it is easy to maintain with no compilation required for changes (WSO2 ESB).

Comment: Another options is to develop the guid generation in an pl/sql function stored in the database, and use a trigger before insert. You call this function when this trigger is fired, and you do not need to send the ID field in the service. This is how database sequences for id generation should be use. This choice makes your system much more cohesive since you do not have the "database business" spread through several systems. I do not know which one is your environment and needs, but this is a very good choice as well.